# What version of Cassandra is Astra?

Tags: cassandra, dbaas, datastax-astra

looking for information on how to confirm which version of Cassandra is running on Astra?

> DataStax Astra Database-as-a-Service Cassandra Made Easy in the Cloud
> Get started in minutes with 5 GB free, no credit card needed. Built on
> open-source Apache Cassandra™ active-everywhere NoSQL. Eliminate the
> overhead to install and operate Cassandra. Enterprise-level
> reliability, security, and management. Deliver applications faster
> with CQL, REST and GraphQL APIs. Deploy dedicated clusters on AWS or
> GCP. Move data in and out of open-source Apache Cassandra.

https://astra.datastax.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It runs a custom version of Cassandra, closer to the Cassandra 4.0, with some functionality from the DataStax Enterprise, like [Storage-Attached Indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/storage-attached-index/6.8/sai/saiQuickStart.html), etc.

If you create a database, and open the CQL console you'll see following message:

```
Connected to caas-cluster at caas-cluster-caas-dc-service:9042.
[cqlsh 6.8.0 | DSE 6.8.4.145 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]
Use HELP for help.
```